# Exclude points from a set of points which prevent them from approximating a function

Tags: computational-mathematics, python

I am currently writing a small program in python for some calculations and to also learn python. I don't have a problem with python itself at the moment but I lack any idea how I could solve the following challenge I encountered when wanting to approximate integrals.

I have a set of points which in the end should approximate an function which I can't solve symbolically. The problem is when I generate those points I get "artifacts". By that I mean points which do not belong on the function.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsEoW.jpg)  is an example which I plotted. On the top right the index is small and gets bigger to the bottom left. Of course there is the loop which forms the sharp bend. All points have different x-values, so I can't really use them as no two points will lay directly above one another.

In the end I only want the lower points, such that the approximated curve is a function. I have tried of ways to find the intersection where I have the sharp bend but I could not identify that point. My idea was to find the intersection by looking for a point with a relatively small index and see if there is a very close point which has a much higher index but a smaller y-value. But with that method I find many possible candidates but can't find the best one without excessive computations.

Unfortunately I can't change the way to find these point, so there is no way to prevent these artifacts...

So I am asking for ideas how an algorithm could work which can reliable remove such artifacts. I hope my questions is clear and fit for math.stackexchange and thanks in advance!

Comment: If I have a function $\int_a^b f(x) dx$, where I can't compute the anti-derrivative $F(x)$ such that $F'(x) = f(x)$, then I generally approximate the integral by crafting a [Reimann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum).  Beyond that, it is difficult to respond to your question unless you edit your question to provide concrete (challenging) mathematical integration problems (i.e. specify the exact value for $f(x)$, and the exact values for the integration end points $a$ and $b$).

Comment: This does not look like "artifacts" to me. It looks like a parametric curve that you are trying to treat as a function of $x$ and are wanting throw away parts of the curve because they don't fit your agenda. Whether this is appropriate, I am not sure, as I have no idea what the integral you are after is supposed to accomplish. But I suggest reconsidering the problem. Maybe you need to integrate the entire curve, not just the lower portion? That is, it is curve $t \mapsto (x(t), y(t))$ and the integral you need is $$A = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} y(t)x'(t)\,dt$$

Comment: If you consider the curve to be the top of a "sheet" that hangs down to the $x$-axis, and folds back over itself when the curve changes directions, that integral gives the area of the sheet.

Comment: Does your curve always look like the one in your picture? Or are you looking for an algorithm that would be able to deal with a wide range of *different* "artifacts"? The  former problem is fairly solvable. Namely, draw a polygonal line through your points and record which line segments intersect each other. There will be (hopefully) *three* pairs of intersections. One of them is the intersection you want: the first segment $[(x_i, y_i),(x_{i+1}, y_{i+1})]$ intersecting *anything* and the last segment $[(x_j, y_j), (x_{j+1}, y_{j+1})]$ intersecting *anything* will intersect each other. (TBC)

Comment: (Cont'd): Now take their intersection as a *new* point $(x, y)$ and consider just the points $(x_1, y_1),\ldots,(x_i, y_i), (x,y), (x_{j+1}, y_{j+1}), \ldots, (x_n, y_n)$ - pass a polygonal line through them and use *that*. You can refine this by passing a more complicated line (e.g. cubic spline) through those points, rather than straight lines, using a similar logic.